# JSF Hello World in Eclipse - can't get it to run :-(

Tags: eclipse, jsf

How you might be able to read from the post title my question will be pretty newbish. I try to understand how to get JSF working with Eclipse and I tried to get a nice and famous Hello world running.

As a template I used the code from the Oracle Java EE 6 Book.

I created this ManagedBean - Hello.java in package de.kuntze

```
package de.kuntze;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class Hello {
    final String world = "Hello World!";

    public String getWorld(){
        return world;
    }
```

}

Can't get any easier... I use this with the following site to pair with - beanhello.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelets Hello World</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    #{hello.world}
</h:body>
</html>
```

Also pretty easy... Here comes the code for web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>CopyCat</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I let this run on the Tomcat 7 server I integrated with Eclipse and the output looks fine for me so far - if I can serve any logging details let me know!

The project's name is "CopyCat" and I expected it to see the managed Bean on my

```
http://localhost:8080/CopyCat/hello
```

but it gives me an 404 error same as the URL

```
http://localhost:8080/CopyCat/
```

and

```
http://localhost:8080/hello.
```

Am I just too stupid to see where my code goes or did I miss something? I know this question is very low level but I just don't get it and don't want to start coding with an existing project - which was already suggested to me :-/

Greetings and thanks in advance for any answers

André

**UPDATE and somehow a solution**

1. Altogether the solution for the problem was using another URL:

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/CopyCat/faces/beanhello
   ```
2. Using tomcat with eclipse gave me some errors (see below) and here are two things I can suggest so far (btw: The JSTL.jar was not necessary for that):

   a) Use the Eclipse workspace by coreservlets (http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/#Getting-Started) as a starting environment.

   b) Change the URL-pattern to ***.jsf**

   and reach the code with the URL

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/beanhello.jsf
   ```

Hope this helps if you are in a similar situation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Doing this I get an 500 error:`exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:229)``root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config`

Comment: you getting some stacktrace ?

Comment: But does Eclipse launch it in its own browser? If so, try to copy and paste the url from the Eclipse browser to your browser, no?

Comment: Hi, copying the URL in a normal browser does not make any difference.

Comment: @Daniel: Is the stacktrace above enough or do you need the whole log?

Comment: @AndreKuntze look at my answer , i Also posted a link to similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `http://localhost:8080/CopyCat/faces/beanhello`

cause your page name is `beanhello.xhtml`

and your *servlet-mapping* *url-pattern* is `/faces/*`

regarding your exception

read this answer by BalusC [Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Dynamic Web Application, Eclipse, JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11328801/617373)

Comment: Will I have to add some additional code to the web.xml like `<html xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">`? I will try it now.

Comment: no , that `xmlns` should be added to the page whenever you will want to use the `c`  tag in particular your web page

Comment: Thanks so far. Using the URL I get `javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:229)` I cleaned the work directory, removed the app and redeployed. What could cause this problem?

Comment: try adding `@ViewScoped` above your `public class Hello {`

Comment: google a bit about the `javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:229)` anyway its unrelatd to the original question , isn't it ?

Comment: In my particular case I would say not because I still cannot get the "Hello world" but I get it my be a problem - somehow - with my system configuration - as all of this is pretty vanilla I am surprised but it's okay. Thanks for pointing me to the right URL to find the code and I will see if I can get the rest up and running :-/

Comment: take a look at this one (without the maven) http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/

Comment: Hi, under http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/#Getting-Started is a running Eclipse setup. I just cannot see the difference right now but maybe I go with that for the start. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Hi, this worked: Changing the URL pattern to `<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>` and reaching the code via the URL `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/beanhello.jsf`... but there is this feeling I cannot really stand: I have no idea why this worked and why the other pattern does not. But I think only starting with JSF I have to take that for the moment.

Comment: strange, maybe upgrading to a more recent jsf implementation would solve the issue...